# A Robust R Function

Tags: r, function, date, dplyr

Based on arms defined below, I wrote these statements under `dplyr::mutate` function to define events. I was wondering if you could help me write a function that can decrease lines of code since some is repetitive? Thanks

```
Arm- 1 (September 1, 2017- August 31, 2018)
 arm_1_event_1  <- c(as.Date("2017-09-01"), as.Date("2017-11-30"))
 arm_1_event_2  <- c(as.Date("2017-12-01"), as.Date("2018-02-28"))
 arm_1_event_3  <- c(as.Date("2018-03-01"), as.Date("2018-05-31"))
 arm_1_event_4  <- c(as.Date("2018-06-01"), as.Date("2018-08-31"))
Arm- 2 (September 1, 2018- August 31, 2019)
  arm_2_event_1  <- c(as.Date("2018-09-01"), as.Date("2018-11-30"))
  arm_2_event_2  <- c(as.Date("2018-12-01"), as.Date("2019-02-28"))
  arm_2_event_3  <- c(as.Date("2019-03-01"), as.Date("2019-05-31"))
  arm_2_event_4  <- c(as.Date("2019-06-01"), as.Date("2019-08-31"))
Arm- 3 (September 1, 2019- August 31, 2020)
  arm_3_event_1  <- c(as.Date("2019-09-01"), as.Date("2019-11-30"))
  arm_3_event_2  <- c(as.Date("2019-12-01"), as.Date("2020-02-29"))
  arm_3_event_3  <- c(as.Date("2020-03-01"), as.Date("2020-05-31"))
  arm_3_event_4  <- c(as.Date("2020-06-01"), as.Date("2020-08-31"))
```

```
dplyr::mutate(
 arms_and_events   =         NA_character_,
 arms_and_events   =         dplyr::case_when(
                                                                                    ((date_application_received >= arm_1_event_1[1] & 
date_application_received <= arm_1_event_1[2])  ~ "arm_1_event_1"),
                                                                                    ((date_application_received >= arm_1_event_2[1] & 
date_application_received <= arm_1_event_2[2])  ~ "arm_1_event_2"),
                                                                                    ((date_application_received >= arm_1_event_3[1] & 
date_application_received <= arm_1_event_3[2])  ~ "arm_1_event_3"),
                                                                                    ((date_application_received >= arm_1_event_4[1] & 
date_application_received <= arm_1_event_4[2])  ~ "arm_1_event_4"),
                                                                                    ((date_application_received >= arm_2_event_1[1] & 
date_application_received <= arm_2_event_1[2])  ~ "arm_2_event_1"),
                                                                                    ((date_application_received >= arm_2_event_2[1] &  
date_application_received <= arm_2_event_2[2])  ~ "arm_2_event_2"),
                                                                                    ((date_application_received >= arm_2_event_3[1] &  
date_application_received <= arm_2_event_3[2])  ~ "arm_2_event_3"),
                                                                                    ((date_application_received >= arm_2_event_4[1] 
& date_application_received <= arm_2_event_4[2]) ~ "arm_2_event_4"),
                                                                                    ((date_application_received >= arm_3_event_1[1] & 
date_application_received <= arm_3_event_1[2])   ~ "arm_3_event_1"),
                                                                                    ((date_application_received >= arm_3_event_2[1] & 
date_application_received <= arm_3_event_2[2])   ~ "arm_3_event_2"),
                                                                                    ((date_application_received >= arm_3_event_3[1] & 
date_application_received <= arm_3_event_3[2])   ~ "arm_3_event_3"),
                                                                                    ((date_application_received >= arm_3_event_4[1] & 
date_application_received <= arm_3_event_4[2])   ~ "arm_3_event_4"),
                                                                                    
((date_voucher_issued       >= arm_1_event_1[1] & 
date_voucher_issued       <= arm_1_event_1[2])   ~ "arm_1_event_1"),

((date_voucher_issued       >= arm_1_event_2[1] & 
date_voucher_issued       <= arm_1_event_2[2]) ~ "arm_1_event_2"),

((date_voucher_issued       >= arm_1_event_3[1] & 
date_voucher_issued       <= arm_1_event_3[2]) ~ "arm_1_event_3"),

((date_voucher_issued       >= arm_1_event_4[1] & 
date_voucher_issued       <= arm_1_event_4[2]) ~ "arm_1_event_4"),
                                                                                    
                                                                                    
((date_voucher_issued       >= arm_2_event_1[1] & 
date_voucher_issued       <= arm_2_event_1[2]) ~ "arm_2_event_1"),
                                                                                    
((date_voucher_issued       >= arm_2_event_2[1] & 
date_voucher_issued       <= arm_2_event_2[2]) ~ "arm_2_event_2"),

((date_voucher_issued       >= arm_2_event_3[1] & 
date_voucher_issued       <= arm_2_event_3[2]) ~ "arm_2_event_3"),
                                                                                    
((date_voucher_issued       >= arm_2_event_4[1] & 
date_voucher_issued       <= arm_2_event_4[2]) ~ "arm_2_event_4"),
                                                                                    
                                                                                    
((date_voucher_issued       >= arm_3_event_1[1] & 
date_voucher_issued       <= arm_3_event_1[2]) ~ "arm_3_event_1"),
                                                                                    
((date_voucher_issued       >= arm_3_event_2[1] & 
date_voucher_issued       <= arm_3_event_2[2]) ~ "arm_3_event_2"),

((date_voucher_issued       >= arm_3_event_3[1] & 
date_voucher_issued       <= arm_3_event_3[2]) ~ "arm_3_event_3"),
                                                                                    
((date_voucher_issued       >= arm_3_event_4[1] & 
date_voucher_issued       <= arm_3_event_4[2]) ~ "arm_3_event_4")
              
       )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we account for NA, this function works:

```
 arms_and_events_function <- function(d)
  {
    df <- data.frame(arm   = rep(1:3, each = 4), 
                     event = rep(1:4, 3),
                     start = as.Date(c("2017-09-01", "2017-12-01", "2018-03-01", 
                                       "2018-06-01", "2018-09-01", "2018-12-01", 
                                       "2019-03-01", "2019-06-01", "2019-09-01", 
                                       "2019-12-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-06-01")),
                     stop  = as.Date(c("2017-11-30", "2018-02-28", "2018-05-31", 
                                       "2018-08-31", "2018-11-30", "2019-02-28", 
                                       "2019-05-31", "2019-08-31", "2019-11-30", 
                                       "2020-02-29", "2020-05-31", "2020-08-31"))
      )
    
      sapply(d, function(x) if(is.na(x)) NA else {
        inds <- which(x >= df$start & x<= df$stop)
        paste0("arm_", df$arm[inds], "_event_", df$event[inds])
      })
  }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your whole code (including the assignations in your first block) could be reduced to a simple function:

```r
arm_and_event <- function(d)
{
  df <- data.frame(arm   = rep(1:3, each = 4), 
                   event = rep(1:4, 3),
                   start = as.Date(c("2017-09-01", "2017-12-01", "2018-03-01", 
                                     "2018-06-01", "2018-09-01", "2018-12-01", 
                                     "2019-03-01", "2019-06-01", "2019-09-01", 
                                     "2019-12-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-06-01")),
                   stop  = as.Date(c("2017-11-30", "2018-02-28", "2018-05-31", 
                                     "2018-08-31", "2018-11-30", "2019-02-28", 
                                     "2019-05-31", "2019-08-31", "2019-11-30", 
                                     "2020-02-29", "2020-05-31", "2020-08-31")))
  
  matches <- sapply(d, function(x) which(x >= df$start & x <= df$stop))  
  paste0("arm", df$arm[matches], "_event", df$event[matches])
}
```

So, for example if we had a vector of dates like this:

```r
date_application_received <- as.Date(c("2017-09-30", "2019-01-05"))
```

Then we can do:

```r
arm_and_event(date_application_received)
#> [1] "arm1_event1" "arm2_event2"
```

With the bonus that our global workspace is not polluted with lots of variables, and the code is far more maintainable.

Comment: I applied this function on the required variable :                                                                 
   ``` arms_and_events   =  arm_and_events_function(d$date_application_received) ```   I am getting the following error:                                                                                   
              Error in df$arm[matches] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Comment: Can you also please explain what this line is doing?                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                               
            matches <- sapply(d, function(x) which(x >= df$start & x <= df$stop))

Comment: The function does not run if I include missing values in a vector. For instant, I get the same error if I run the function with date_application_received <- as.Date(c("2017-09-30", NA,  "2019-01-05"))

Comment: How do I account for missing using the same function?